# Speech recognition game

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I want to ask. I want to make a speech recognition game. I want to, example, when the question "Say A" and i say "A", the answer is true. And when the question "B" and i say "M", the answer is false. But i have a problem :
1. Did i must create database for word category?
2. How to make the one question and one answer ? Example, when the question "Say A" and i say "A", the answer is true.
3. If i must create database, where i must implement it in speech recognition class ?
Thank you and sorry for my bad english.

Here is my Speech Recognition code

```
public class MainGame extends AppCompatActivity {


private TextView jawabanTxt;
private String textA;
TextView textView;

SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_game_act);
    jawabanTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jawabanTxt);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);



}

public void getSpeechInput(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,Locale.getDefault());


if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 10);
} else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Perangkat anda tidak  mendukung", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode,data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case 10:
        if ((resultCode == RESULT_OK &&data != null)) {
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            jawabanTxt.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
        }
}
```

And here is my db Code (if needed)

```
public class dbGame extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "huruf.db";
private static final String DATABASE_VERSION = "1";
public dbGame(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, Integer.parseInt(DATABASE_VERSION));
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table game(huruf);";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    sql = "INSERT INTO game (huruf) VALUES('a','b','c','d');";
    db.execSQL((sql));

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
```

And here is my "Letter" category

```
public class HurufActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.huruf_activity);
    ImageButton aBtn,bBtn,cBtn,d;

    aBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.aBtn);
    bBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bBtn);


    aBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HurufActivity.this, MainGame.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    bBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(HurufActivity.this, MainGame.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Did i must create database for word category?

It would be very handy to have the possibility to extend your program with questions and words instead of just letters. If you are only planning on using the alphabet in your program you can just use an array or a list to add all 26 characters.

2. How to make the one question and one answer ? Example, when the question "Say A" and i say "A", the answer is true.

I would advise you to make two methods, one to ask the questions (maybe trough argument input) and one to check the answer the user has given. I guess the challenge is to think of a way you think it is handy to specify a correct answer. With speech recognition software you can probably generate a boolean output to check the answer and you can use that to pass trough as a 'correct' or 'incorrect'.

3. If i must create database, where i must implement it in speech recognition class?
   Again, a database shouldn´t be necessary but if you'd like to use one you can try it via direct queries or JPA repo's.

Here's a very good article about JPA: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases